# Make a certain area of a shape/text a different colour

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I have this:

[image: Adobe Fireworks]

I've been searching for tutorials online on how to change the colour of part of a shape/text, but I have not found anything and I also do not know what this particular method is called.

I tried using the various variants from the `Combine Path` menu (which I have used before to create various shapes), but it has been a no-go.

How can I make the inside part of the 'B' white, while leaving the part of the 'B' outside the circle it's current colour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click (Windows) or Control-Click (Mac) the letter and choose `Convert to Paths`.

Duplicate and place a second circle above a duplicated letter as a guide for your cut

Select both paths, the circle above the B

In the **Path Panel** (<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)

Click **Punch Paths** to cut the circle shape out of the B

You now have the original B and a cut shape capable of a different color.

[image]

Comment: D'oh! Completely forgot about `Convert to Paths!`. Thanks!